# How to retrieve something that doesn't exist?

Tags: lotusscript

I have two views: view1 and view2.

view1 contains list of 26 staff(A-Z).

view2 contains list of docs created by each staff each day(each staff can only create 1 doc per day). Each of these doc contains the name of the staff who created it,
and the date which it is created(not the built-in notes creation date). So that means, for January 2012, staff A has 31 docs,
February 2012 - 29 docs, and so on until today(August 16,2012 - 16 docs for August 2012).

My situation currently is that for some staff, there are missing doc(s). For example, staff A is missing document on 27/4/2010,
staff B missing docs on 5/12/2011 and 3/4/2012, staff C and so on. The missing docs varies for each staff. Some has no missing docs,
some missing up to 10 docs.

Now I want to retrieve the date which a doc is missing and put it on a text file. Say staff B above is missing 2 docs on the 
said dates so in my text file I'll display "Staff B - 5/12/2011,3/4/2012". But how do I retrieve something if it does not even exist
at the first place?

So far I've only think of counting the date range for a period, say 1/1/2010 until 16/8/2012. Count how many days are there in that
range, then count the total docs for a staff. If total docs is not equal to the number of days in that range, then some doc(s) are missing.
But I still need on which date are the missing doc(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way for you to solve this would be to walk the date range for each staff member and output the missing dates.

Assuming you're thinking of lotusscript, something like (not tested, the indexing of the views and the way the dates are stored could cause issues).

```
Sub Initialize
    Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim viewStaff As NotesView
Dim viewDocs As NotesView
Dim docStaff As NotesDocument
Dim docDoc As NotesDocument
Dim keys(1) As String
Dim startDate As New NotesDateTime("1/1/2005") 'Start date of Range
Dim endDate As New NotesDateTime("1/1/2010") 'End date of Range  
Dim tempDate As NotesDateTime

'Initialise Views
Set db = session.currentDatabase
Set viewStaff = db.GetView("StaffView")
Set viewDocs = db.GetView("DocsByStaff")

'Iterate over staff to process
Set docStaff = viewStaff.Getfirstdocument()
While Not docStaff Is Nothing
    'Search for daily docs for this staff member (this will need a view indexed on the staff member name, then the date)
    keys(0) = docStaff.Fullname(0) 'Or whatever this item is called

    Set tempDate = startDate
    While tempDate.Timedifference(endDate) <= 0 'Go over each date up to and including the end date
        keys(1) = tempdate.Dateonly
        Set docDoc = viewDocs.getDocumentByKey(keys) 'Search for date using current user and date
        If docDoc Is Nothing Then 'Haven't found it
            Print "Can't find document for " + keys(0) + " on " + keys(1) ' Could output to file or something here.
        End If
        tempDate.Adjustday(1) 'Roll forward another day
    Wend

    Set docStaff = viewStaff.getNextDocument(docStaff) 'Next staff member
Wend

End Sub
```

Probably not the most efficient way of doing it, but if it's a once in a while and you don't have too many docs, this approach should suffice.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works but I have to create a new view(viewDocs2) which the 1st column is a string-'FullName+@Text(@Date(docDate)) and in code above use the same string for lookup. Anyway, from your code it means keys(0) will look at 1st column(staff name) and if found it will use keys(1) to look at 2nd column(date) is it? I don't quite understand the use of multiple keys to search 1 view. Initially my viewDocs 1st and 2nd column are FullName and docDate respectively(FullName is sorted but not grouped) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Yup, the [documentation](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/lotusscript/lotusscript.nsf/1efb1287fc7c27388525642e0074f2b6/1dab5f849a6879018525642e0075cde0?OpenDocument) for getDocumentByKey says you can either have a single string, or an arry of strings for the key. Each element in the array corresponds to a sorted column in the view. You will probably need to convert the date to text in the view though (@Text(YourDate)). If you concat column works, just go with that though.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know about the List data type in LotusScript?  I'm thinking you should create an exhaustive list of booleans covering the date range.  I.e., there's a list entry for each day in the range, with the date as the listtag and the entry value indicating whether the doc has been found.  You start with a list that's initialized so that every date is false:

```
Dim theDate As New NotesDateTime("1/1/2005")
dim endDate as New NotesDateTime("8/16/2012")
dim foundDates List as Boolean

While theDate.Timedifference(endDate) <= 0
  foundDates(theDate.dateOnly) = false
wend
```

You'll probably want the above code in a function so you can re-initialize the list for each staff member.

Now you'll want code to iterate through all docs for one member your Staff.  Read the date item from the doc, and change the corresponding list entry to true.

```
dateObj = new NotesDateTime(doc.getItemValue("dateFieldName"))
foundDates(dateObj.dateOnly) = true
```

After the loop through the docs for the staff member, you have a List that contains true for the date of every doc that was found, and false for every date that was not found.

Now you can now use a forall to output a list of the dates that were not found simply by checking for entries that are still false.

```
print #textfile, StaffName;
ForAll dateEntry in foundDates
   if dateEntry = false then
      print #textfile, listtag(dateEntry)
   end if
End ForAll
print #textfile,
```

Enclose all of the above in a loop through the all the staff members, being sure to reinitialize all entries in the foundDate list to false before processing the docs for each staff member.

Comment: I agree, that is the way i would have done it too, with a small difference. Instead of setting the value to true, I would delete the list item: `dateObj = new NotesDateTime(doc.getItemValue("dateFieldName")) If IsElement(foundDates(dateObj.dateOnly)) = True Then Erase foundDates(dateObj.dateOnly) End If` Then you don't have to perform the test for true/false in the ForAll loop, you already have the list of false/missing items. But that is just a preference.